# Gitlab CI how to deploy to different environments using different runners?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I use gitflow for my branching feature-branches, develop, master + release. On top, I have multiple environments dev and multiple tests in one account and stage and prod in another. Now I want to have one "runner" in each account and want to deploy to each of these environments with Gitlab CI.

- Branches

  - feature/*
  - develop
  - master
  - release
- Environments

  - Account test - one runner here

    - dev
    - test
  - Account prod - one runner here

    - stage
    - prod

I came across environments ... but do not know what benefit they bring beyond visibility, I tinker with tags and could link runners to jobs by tags ... which is quite inflexible.

Can you help me out how to do this without having one job for each environment, resulting in a lot of jobs and a loooong .gitlab-ci.yml?

Answer (score 0):

Here, do we need to have one job for each environment? Since you have 2 account groups, one test (feature, develop, etc.) and the other one as prod (master, release), are you ok with having 2 jobs for each of these?

Comment: I would love to have one job and just "apply" them to the different environments and accounts. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes that is possible, if you variablize values( like environment, account, tags, etc) and pass them according to the account you want to run for, from the CICD settings. Or else keeping different jobs is an option.

Comment: do you know how I can parameterize especially the tag so that it can only be two values from a list? I bound the runner to the tag and would love the executer to have only two options.

Comment: Unfortunately Gitlab does not have support for variable expansion in tags. So keeping 2 different jobs is the only solution for now it seems. To check what all supports variable expansion, refer this doc https://docs.gitlab.com/14.2/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html